# Why would a preload behave differently in the local dev version of the site vs. the local exported version of the site?

Tags: svelte, sapper

Svelte 3.34.0, Sapper 0.28.10.

File at `/src/routes/data/index.svelte`. Url pattern is `http://localhost:3000/data/?day=40` or `http://localhost:3000/data/` (defaults to current day). The page fetches JSON data from a remote url and displays it.

```
<script context="module">
  import { buildDataUrl, formatDate } from '../../helpers';
  import moment from 'moment';

  export async function preload(page) {
    const query = page.query;
    let day = Number.parseInt(query.day);
    if (Number.isNaN(day)) day = moment().dayOfYear();
    console.log(`preload fired, day: ${day}, ${JSON.stringify(query)}`);
    const get = await this.fetch(buildDataUrl(day), {
```

When I run this locally in dev mode with `sapper dev` the url query param is respected and used correctly. The page will re-render when the query string changes, either by editing it or clicking on a link on the page.

When I run this locally with `npx sapper export && npx serve __sapper__/export` (see docs [here](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#sapper_export)) and go to `http://localhost:5000/data/?day=40`  the day value always defaults to the current day, regardless of what is in the query string. Even using `?day=a` will not change the behavior -- this should result in an error.

Docs for preload are [here](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading).

This feels like a bug but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the chat with the devs on Discord I found that you have to use the page store to access the query string and then run any async fetches in your page script, not module script.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this but, even when exported it works as expected on my machine.

And since you have this line `if (Number.isNaN(day)) day = moment().dayOfYear();` even if you pass a `NaN` to the query it replaces with the current day so I don't see why it is supposed to result in an Error

Comment: Nah I went through this yesterday and the answer is that preload in a module context isn't intended to be used this way (according to Discord). You have to use the page store to access the query string and then run any async fetches in your page script, not module script.

Comment: Ok, will keep that in mind for future refence :)